# Имплементация метода интерфейса во фрагменте android

Tags: android

Я решил использовать Navigation Drawer(стандартно созданный средствами Android Studio) и переключаюсь в нем между несколькими фрагментами. Так вот в одном из фрагментов(GalleryFragment) у меня есть RecyclerView и для него я написал класс OrderListAdapter и в этом классе я вызываю метод интерфейса `openFragment(position)` имплементация которого находится в GalleryFragment.

MainNavigationActivity

```
class MainNavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_navigation)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_navigation, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
   }
```

GalleryFragment

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OpenFragment,
FragmentData {

private lateinit var viewModel: GalleryViewModel

private lateinit var recyclerOrders: RecyclerView

private lateinit var adapter: OrderListAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    initializeRecycler()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (this::adapter.isInitialized)
        displayData()
}


private fun initializeRecycler() {
    recyclerOrders = requireView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_orders)
    recycler_orders.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycler_orders.layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()))

    viewModel.loadingState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when (it.status) {
            LoadingState.Status.FAILED -> Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                it.msg,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            LoadingState.Status.RUNNING -> Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "Loading",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            LoadingState.Status.SUCCESS -> displayData()
        }
    })
}

private fun displayData() {
    val tmpArrayOrders = ArrayList<Order>()
    for (tmp in viewModel.orders) {
        if (status[viewModel.actualStatus].value == tmp.status || status[viewModel.actualStatus].value < 0) {
            tmpArrayOrders.add(tmp)
        }
    }


    adapter = OrderListAdapter(requireContext(), tmpArrayOrders)
    recyclerOrders.adapter = adapter
}

override fun openFragment(position: Int) {
    val fragment = OrderFragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putInt("position", position)
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
        .replace(R.id.order_fragment, fragment)
        .commit()
}

 }
```

OpenFragment (интерфейс)

```
interface OpenFragment {
fun openFragment(position: Int)
 }
```

OrderListAdapter

```
class OrderListAdapter(
var context: Context,
var orderList: List<Order>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var mDataPasser: OpenFragment

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderListViewHolder {
    mDataPasser = context as OpenFragment
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent, false)
    return OrderListViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrderListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val order = orderList[position]

    var tmpStatus: String = ""
    for (tmp in status) {
        if (tmp.value == order.status) {
            tmpStatus = tmp.name
        }
    }

    holder.id.text = order.id.toString()
    holder.adres.text = order.adres.toString()
    holder.user_id.text = order.user_id.toString()
    holder.cena.text = order.cena.toString()
    holder.status.text = tmpStatus.toString()
    holder.data.text = order.data.toString()

    holder.card.setOnClickListener {
        mDataPasser.openFragment(position)
    }


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return orderList.size
}
  }
```

Так вот, во фрагменте я инициализирую adapter и передаю context `adapter = OrderListAdapter(requireContext(), tmpArrayOrders)` и тут сама проблема. Так как я передаю context активити, а не фрагмента, то компилятор ругается на то, что нет имплементации метода интерфейса в активити. Это логично, т.к. передаю контекс активити и если заимплементировать метод в активити, то все будет работать. Но я бы не хотел загрязнять активити, чтобы это все оставалось во фрагменте.

Сама ошибка:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.staff.MainNavigationActivity cannot be cast to com.example.staff.model.OpenFragment
```

Отсюда следует вопрос: как передать context именно фрагмента? Либо как правильно имплементировать методы интерфейса во фрагменте?

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое изменение адаптера:

```
class OrderListAdapter(
    var context: Context,
    var orderList: List<Order>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var mDataPasser: OpenFragment // private modifier REMOVED

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderListViewHolder {
        //mDataPasser = context as OpenFragment REMOVED
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent, false)
        return OrderListViewHolder(view)
}

    ...
}
```

И создание из фрагмента:

```
    adapter = OrderListAdapter(requireContext(), tmpArrayOrders)
    adapter.mDataPasser = this // ADDED
    recyclerOrders.adapter = adapter
```

Можно и отдельно передавать OpenFragment через конструктор адаптера. Ничего не мешает передать и контекст и OpenFragment как отдельные поля.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже переделал navigation drawer для смены активити, а не фрагментов. Вот по этому примеру: https://www.fluttercode.site/2017/04/navigation-drawer-in-every-activity.html